# MS SQL: Can't connect to server with anything but 127.0.0.1 on the server machine

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm not able to connect to sql server with anything but 127.0.0.1 on the server machine.  If I try to connect via actual IP on the network it does not work locally or remotely.

The environment is SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2000.  My goal is to connect to this SQL Server instance from a remote machine.

I've tried telneting to port 1433 using the actual IP and that fails.
I've tried turning off Windows Firewall completely

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked tcp/ip is enabled in SQL server configuration manager? And that allow remote connections is enabled on the SQL server instance?

Comment: Yes, tcp/ip is enabled and remote connections is enabled for tcp/ip only

Comment: can you ping the server machine from remote? (I assume you have turned off the firewall on the server at this point) what is the IP that your are connecting to via SSMS on remote machine?

Comment: Yes I can ping it from the remote machine.  I do have the firewall turned off on the server.  The IP that I'm connecting to is 192.1.3.11

Comment: do a `netstat -a` on the server, make sure it's listening on port 1433. Then, if you can't telnet to 1433 from a remote host, something in your network is filtering it.

Comment: netstat -a says TIME_WAIT for this port.  Going to research that now, any ideas in case I cant find anything?

Comment: Alex, did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing a very similar problem here. SQL Server configured to run on 1433 on all IP addresses. No firewall. Can telnet to 1433 on 127.0.0.1 but not on any of the configured IP addresses. SQL server is set to allow remote access. SQL server logs say it's listening on 1443 on 'any'. It's driving us nuts! P.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running multiple instances?

Make sure that TCP connections are enabled.

Make sure a connection is allowed by your firewall, or that the firewall is disabled.

If you have trouble with either of these after making changes, try re-starting the DB and SQL Server Browser (or disable Browser).

Comment: No, just the default instance.  TCP connections are enabled.  Firewall is turned off.  I have tried restarting the DB and the SQL Server Browser is disabled.  Still no luck :-/